# How is the plone-overview.pt template rendered in the Zope2 application root (in Plone)?

Tags: plone, zope

[Plone](http://plone.org/) has a nice hack that does away with the boring **Zope Quickstart** page that ships with Zope2. It changes this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Relevant code is located in `Products/CMFPlone/browser/admin.zcml` (https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/browser/admin.zcml#L35):

```
  <browser:page
      for="OFS.interfaces.IApplication"
      name="plone-overview"
      class=".admin.Overview"
      permission="zope.Public"
      template="templates/plone-overview.pt"
      />
```

And that explains why `http://localhost:8080/plone-overview` renders the plone-overview template, but why/how does the application root i.e. `http://localhost:8080` render the same template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That same ZCML file registers a [`AppTraverser` adapter](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/browser/admin.zcml#L57); this adapter adapts the `OFS.interfaces.IApplication` object to `IRequest` to intercept traversal.

In the `IRequest` adapter `publishTraverse()` method, when the `index_html` name is traversed over, the adapter returns the same `plone-overview` view:

```
def publishTraverse(self, request, name):
    if name == 'index_html':
        view = queryMultiAdapter((self.context, request),
                    Interface, 'plone-overview')
        if view is not None:
            return view
    return DefaultPublishTraverse.publishTraverse(self, request, name)
```

See the [`AppTraverser` class definition](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/browser/admin.py#L34).

Comment: Mystery finally revealed, Dank je wel! +1